# How can I send the last column of the first line to standard output?

Tags: bash

For example

The file TEMPFILE.TXT contains this:

```
PROC-|STUFF_THINGS|MORE STUFF|PING|AUTOSYS
PROC-|ASTUFF_THINGS_XX_2|Print-Wire|AUTONON
```

I only want to print `AUTOSYS` to standard output.

Comment: `IFS="|" read -ra array < file; echo "${array[${#array[@]}-1]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==1 {print $NF; exit}' file
```

If you don't mind hardcoding the number of columns, then:

```
head -1 file | cut -d'|' -f5
```

Column-count agnostic approach, but more round-about and expensive:

```
head -1 file | rev | cut -f1 -d'|' | rev
```

In all these, we are only reading the first line of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
while read line ;do echo "${line##*|}";break;done
```